# What happens first? View controller's own initialization or a segue's?

Tags: ios, swift

If I declare a variable in my UIViewController like:

```
var test: String = "normal"
```

But I also have a segue whose destination is the original viewcontroller and states:

```
destinyViewController.test = "rare"
```

What happens when the segue starts the original view? What value the test var ends with?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try it and let us know...

Comment: Hint: The latter form does not *initialize* the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making an instance of original viewcontroller from some another view controller and assigning `test` value like, `destinyViewController.test = "rare"`, It will use "rare" as `test` value. but if you are not setting anything from anywhere else, `test` will still have "normal" into it self.